# Sharepoint Online issuse: Edit File

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file

I am editing file and library on SharePoint online: just add a few columns to the library. I saved and saw these changes displayed on the page. 
But after 12-24 hours, I returned to the library and found the changes were lost.
This error also occurs for file edits.

P/s: I checked to sure that I'm the only one who has edited this library. And all file are updated.

How can I fix this error?

Thanks,

TrungPN

Answer (score 0):

Trung,
For file edits, Can you find the version history in SharePoint online? If the file is in OneDrive for business, you can also check the version history in OneDrive. Or please try to find the unsaved files in Office.

For added columns, please go list settings to check if the column is just hidded.

Also you can check audit log in admin center>security and compliance>search>audit log search for more logs concerning the library with issue.

Test with other libraries to see if the issue occurs

Comment: Thank for your reply. But As I mentioned above, all files have been updated to the latest version. Now I have an error: **the file is locked for shared use by...**
Any ideal to fix this?